# Transparent/Opaque Navigation Bar is Behind "div" with Class "transbox"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I started off with some text over a background image for the home page on my website. I wanted to make the letters more legible so I added an opaque box using the class "transbox" and setting it's opacity. I'm not too concerned about the text being transparent, but now the navigation bar that I have set up sits behind the "transbox" and will not let me click the links when I scroll over the "transbox" since it is sitting over the navigation bar.

I have already tried setting the z-index appropriately and even went through changing the classes and css code to make it simply a transparent container with some text, however the problem persists and new issues arise regarding container/text placement.

All I want is the navbar to be over everything so it is not covered and unusable in any situation as the user scrolls through the page. I'm curious if this is a bug with opacity, if I am using the wrong type of class, or if it is something entirely different.

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop()){
      $('nav').addClass('black');
      $('header').addClass('black');
      $('header .logo img').addClass('black');
      $('header ul').addClass('black');
      $('header a').addClass('black');
    }
    else
    {
      $('nav').removeClass('black');
      $('header').removeClass('black');
      $('header .logo img').removeClass('black');
      $('header ul').removeClass('black');
      $('header a').removeClass('black');
    }
  })
```

```css
header{
  background: #35424a;
  color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 999;
}

header.black{
  z-index: 999;
}

header a{
  color: #5ff5a3;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow:
    -1px -1px 0 #000,
    1px -1px 0 #000,
    -1px 1px 0 #000,
    1px 1px 0 #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: .5s;
}

header a.black{
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
}

header ul{
  float: right;
  padding: 68px 50px 0 10px;
  display: flex;
  transition: .5s;
}

header ul.black{
  padding: 40px 10px 0 10px;
}

header li{
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1px;
  transition: .5s;
}

header nav{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: .5s;
}

header nav.black{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  color: #000000;
}

header .current a, header a:hover{
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #000000;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  transition: .5s;
}

header .logo img
{
  width: 500px;
  padding: 0px 50px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  transition: .5s;
}

header .logo img.black
{
  width: 300px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

#showcase{
  min-height: 1000px;
  background: url(../img/showcaseimg.jpg) no-repeat 0 -200px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#showcase h1{
  font-size: 55px;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

#showcase p{
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0px 20px 20px;
}

#showcase .transbox{
  margin-top: 700px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity: 0.6;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
      <div class="container">
        <nav>
          <div class="logo">
            <img src="./img/creativecs_logo.png">
          </div>
          <ul>
            <li class="current"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>

    <section id="showcase">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="transbox">
          <h1>Custom PC solutions for anyone and everyone.</h1>
          <p>Designed by engineers. Tested by enthusiasts. Check out what CreativeCS has to offer you.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It work fine for me.
That being said, for z-index to work you need your elements with z-index to be positionned ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)).

```
header {
position:relative;
z-index: 999;}

#showcase {
position:relative;
z-index: 1;
}
```

You might need to read about the [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).
Here header and #showcase exist in the stacking context of the root element (html) so it will work fine. Other times you might want to create a stacking context that is not as high as the root element.

Comment: Thank you!! that's all I needed. everything else was fine. The css code I posted was without an opacity setting for the transbox so I think that's why it was working fine when you and Stefan Avramovic tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seams to be fine, anchors do fire as expected, you can add this script to see wich element is selected..

```
 var x =  document.getElementsByTagName("*")
      for(var i = 0; i< x.length; i++){
          x[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
            alert(e.target.tagName)
          })
      }
```

Comment: thank you for your response! I was missing a single line of code stating that the position was relative to other parts of the page. My css code was missing the setting for opacity on the transbox and I think that's why it was working fine when you tried it.